# Multivariate Integral in PRML, Bishop

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've read Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning in Chapter 10, 465p. I don't understand some multivariate integral parts.

Let $q(\mathbf{Z})=\prod_{i=1}^{M} q_{i}\left(\mathbf{Z}_{i}\right)$, and $\mathcal{L}(q)=\int q(\mathbf{Z}) \ln \left\{\frac{p(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Z})}{q(\mathbf{Z})}\right\} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{Z}$. Insert q(Z) into L(q), then we obatin this formula. ($q_i(Z_i) = q_i$). The author tries to optimize a functional $\mathcal{L}(q)$ with respect to $q_j$. So, the author reorganize $\mathcal{L}(q)$ which only specify $q_j$ term as follows.

\begin{aligned} \mathcal{L}(q) &=\int \prod_{i} q_{i}\left\{\ln p(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Z})-\sum_{i} \ln q_{i}\right\} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{Z} \\ &=\int q_{j}\left\{\int \ln p(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Z}) \prod_{i \neq j} q_{i} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{Z}_{i}\right\} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{Z}_{j}-\int q_{j} \ln q_{j} \mathrm{d} \mathbf{Z}_{j}+\text { const } \end{aligned}

I have two incomprehensible parts of the above equation.

(1) In the first term, I don't understand how $\int dZ$ is changed into $\int dZ_1dZ_2...dZ_m$
(2) In the second term, I think $-\int \prod_{i} q_{i}\sum_{i}\ln q_idZ$ is changed into $-\int q_j\ln q_j dZ_j + const$. But I think $\int Z_i$ terms should remain inside the $\int q_j \ln q_j dZ_j$ same as the first term.

Can anybody elaborate this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1), the author is using $\bf Z$ as shorthand for the vector $({\bf Z}_1,\ldots,{\bf 
 Z}_M)$ so the integral was always a multiple integral over $d{\bf Z}_1\cdots d{\bf Z}_M$.

For (2), you are correct about what happened to $\int \prod_{i} q_{i}\sum_{i}\ln q_idZ$. But remember that each $q_i$ is a distribution, so that $\int q_i dZ_i=1$. In detail, the expression $\int \prod_{i} q_{i}\sum_{i}\ln q_idZ$ became
$$\begin{align}\int \left(\prod_{i} q_{i}\right)\left(\ln q_j + \sum_{k\ne j}\ln q_k\right)dZ
&=\int \left(\prod_{i} q_{i}\right)\ln q_j dZ +\int \left(\prod_{i} q_{i}\right)\sum_{k\ne j}\ln q_k dZ\\
&=A+B
\end{align}\tag1
$$
where $B$ does not depend on $j$. As for $A$, all the terms in $\prod_i q_i$ involving $i$ different from $j$ have been integrated out (with value $1$), leaving just the integral $\int q_j \ln q_j dZ_j$.